# Class type as field in Java

Tags: java, class

My question might seem weird, and I don't know if it possible, but there it is :

I have several classes (UseCases) all implementing an interface => `IUseCase`.

```
UseCase1 implementing IUseCase
UseCase2 implementing IUseCase
etc.
```

I also have another class "`UseCaseContext`" that is supposed to carry some information about several usecases.

My goal would be to have **one** instance of `UseCaseContext` per `UseCase`. To do that, I would need a **field** in the UseCaseContext that tells me if this context is either related to UseCase1 or UseCase2 or etc.

So, rather than storing an instance of the UseCase in a field, is there another way to determine if to which `UseCase` is my `UseCaseContext` related to ?

I know this is might be confusing, so please, tell me if you need me to explain it otherwise :)

Thank you !

Comment: you can use `Class` object as a field.

Comment: It seems like you want a `Map<Class, UseCaseContext>`?

Comment: are you looking for the singleton pattern?

Comment: @cdhowie: Not really a Map, just a field that would help me indentifying what UseCase I am dealing with !

Comment: @ogzd: I think the Class field is probably what I am looking for, then should I store something like "myusecase.class" in it ?

Comment: @duffy356: no singleton, one real instance per usecase :)

Comment: @FloranGmehlin i think all answers will be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, indeed ! I cannot really choose which one is the best, but clearly, all of you guys answered very well my question. thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public class UseCaseContext {

     private Class useCaseClass;

     public UseCaseContext(Class useCaseClass) {
        this.useCaseClass = useCaseClass;
     }
 }
```

Then you can simply call: `new UseCaseContext(instance.getClass())`.

Answer (score 5):

As already pointed out in the comments, just store a class reference in your `UseCaseContext`:

```
public class UseCaseContext 
{
  private Class<? extends IUseCase> useCaseClass;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IUseCase some_instance = new UseCaseX();
String className = some_instance.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

This will return UseCaseX as string. Is that what you want?

P.S. If you do not want string name of class you can use class object (Class clazz = some_instance.getClass()) to distinguish one UseCase from another.

Comment: Why use the name instead of `Class`?